# Subquery returns more than 1 row (1242)

Tags: mysql, sql, typeorm

I'm trying to update a table by his Primary Key, but MySQL(AWS RDS) is returning an error that says "Subquery returns more than 1 row". I'm already done the select with same "where" and just return one row. Also, I added join, but I'm still having the same result.

I'm using TypeOrm but doing directly the query get same result.

Code NestJs:

```
const result = await this.matchRepository.createQueryBuilder('match')
            .update(Match)
            .set({ estado_match })
            .where('id_match = :id_match', { id_match })
            .execute()
```

Create Table:

```
create table matchs_publicacion
(
    id_match            varchar(36)                                       not null primary key,
    id_pub_similar      varchar(255)                                      not null,
    id_publicacion      varchar(255)                                      not null,
    estado_match        enum ('A', 'C', 'E') default 'A'                  not null,
    fecha_creacion      datetime(6)          default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) not null,
    fecha_actualizacion datetime(6)          default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) not null on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
    constraint IDX_20c51c411bd0bdb8d28e503ab9
        unique (id_pub_similar, id_publicacion)
);
```

Query:

```
UPDATE matchs_publicacion SET estado_match = 'C', fecha_actualizacion = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id_match = '9b8b9090-0cc7-459e-a4a6-79960f39bd0a'
```

Comment: There is no sub query - have you checked update triggers on this table?

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, there is a trigger, maybe can be the problem. The trigger do this 
`update publicacion
        set estado_publi = 'C'
        where id_publicacion in (
(select id_publicacion from matchs_publicacion where estado_match = 'C'),
(select id_pub_similar from matchs_publicacion where estado_match = 'C'));`
Subqueries can return more than one row, but update may update those rows, right? By the "IN" clause.